# I will like to find duplicates in a data frame base on name and last name. Using partial string matching

Tags: r, duplicates, match, stringr

this is a example data frame and I just want to se if their any unction that can find duplicates , using partial string matching.

df

```
name   last
Joseph Smith
Jose   Smith
Joseph Smit
Maria  Cruz
maria  cru
Mari   Cruz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Data Prep

Using `dplyr`, first concatenate the `first` and `last` name into a `whole` name

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
          rowwise() %>%              # rowwise operation
          mutate(whole=paste0(name,last,collapse=""))  # concatenate first and last name by row
          ungroup()                  # remove rowwise grouping
```

Output

```
    name   last       whole
1 Joseph  Smith JosephSmith
2   Jose  Smith   JoseSmith
3 Joseph   Smit  JosephSmit
4  Maria   Cruz   MariaCruz
5  maria    cru    mariacru
6   Mari   Cruz    MariCruz
```

#### Grouping similar strings

This recursive function will use `agrepl`, logical approximate grep, to find related string groups, and group and label them `grp`. **NOTE** The tolerance to differences among strings is set by `max.distance`. Lower numbers are more stringent

```
desired <- NULL
grp <- 1    
special <- function(x, y, grp) {
                if (nrow(y) < 1) {        # if y is empty return data
                     return(x)
                } else {
                     similar <- agrepl(y$whole[1], y$whole, max.distance=0.4)      # find similar occurring strings
                     x <- rbind(x, y[similar,] %>% mutate(grp=grp))    # save similar strings
                     y <- setdiff(y, y[similar,])        # remaining non-similar strings
                     special(x, y, grp+1)       # run function again on non-similar strings
                }
            }

desired <- special(desired, df1, grp)
```

Output

```
    name   last       whole   grp
1 Joseph  Smith JosephSmith     1
2   Jose  Smith   JoseSmith     1
3 Joseph   Smit  JosephSmit     1
4  Maria   Cruz   MariaCruz     2
5  maria    cru    mariacru     2
6   Mari   Cruz    MariCruz     2
```

To get rid of `whole`

```
df2 <- df1 %>% select(-whole)
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, I have also tried other partial text matching like pmach etc.